# Can we use Android TranslateAnimation for 2 different location?

Tags: android, translate-animation

TranslateAnimation is use when you want to move image in different possintion **like**

1. left to right
2. up to down
3. one XYscalse position to other XYscale position

***Syntax***

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(StartinXscale,StartingYscale,EndXscale,EndYscale);
```

***Methods***

```
animation.setDuration(millisecond);//move speed.
animation.setRepeatCount(int value);//how many time you want to move it from starting to ending position.
animation.setRepeatMode(int value);//mode like goto destination and return back to main position. 
imageView.startAnimation(animation);//Start animation on imageView
```

> Can we use above code twice time in one activity?

---

***MyCode***

```
private void animationAction() {
        float StartX = 500.0f;
        float StartY = -300.0f;
        float EndX = -300.0f;
        float EndY = 500.0f;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <2; i++) {
                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(StartX,StartX + EndX, StartY, StartY + EndY);
                animation.setDuration(3000);
                animation.setRepeatCount(5);
                animation.setRepeatMode(2);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
                EndX = 300.0f;

        }
```

> In MyCode result was only execute one time

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Animation
    private Animation animMove;
    private Animation animFadein;

//Method to preform 2 animation in sequence  

private void doAnimation() {
        // load the animation
        animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
        // start move up animation on brnetwork text
        imageView.startAnimation(animMove);
        // set animation listener
        animMove.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                Resources res = getResources();
                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
                relMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

                llInput.startAnimation(animFadein);
                llInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvSignUp.startAnimation(animFadein);
                tvVideo.startAnimation(animFadein);
                tvSignUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // set animation listener
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }

after MOVE animation i have to perform FEDIN animation
in your case you can replace FEDIN by your Next Animation.
```